# Different user interface than usual on Facebook app

Tags: facebook, motorola-droid-razr

Whenever I download the Facebook app for my Android phone (Motorola Razr D3) it shows up normal for the first time but then changes to a strange interface and then stays that way.

[image: Picture]

<sup>(Click picture for larger variant)</sup>

I've tried deleting it and then downloading it again and again but it keeps changing back, what is this? What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you are very lucky to have that UI (user interface). I've been waiting to get that version, to no avail.

What you have is the Holo-fied UI of Facebook, which I think was initially available to selected alpha testers of the Facebook app. A group would get the Holo version, while the rest would get the regular version. This concept is called A/B testing. Eventually, if there are no more issues, everybody will that that UI. Have you, by any chance, applied as an alpha / beta tester?

Holo, as described in WikiPedia, is the Google recommended theme for the design of Android apps, introduced with Android version 4.0.

Is there a way to change the interface? NO, because the UI is determined by Facebook's servers. If you attempted to download and install (by sideloading) a Holo-fied version of Facebook, and you were not given the rights to have this UI, you would be reverted to the regular UI. This is the reason why [Holofication Nation](http://holonation.co.uk/) cannot make a custom Holo-fied version of Facebook. To date, they have already released a Holo-fied UI for Grooveshark, Steam, and Instagram. (and I think for CNN too!)

Comment: Thanks! I was getting worried it was some kind of virus or something, no wonder why this version is all full of glitches and bugs